# Angle chasing proof

Tags: triangles, angle, quadrilateral

Given the following diagram, how can we prove angle CDA is 2x. We are told CB = AB. How do we prove this without using alternate segment theorem? I can't seem to do it.

Problem:
[image]

Comment: Is there any reason not to use the alternate segment theorem? I think it's the most simple and good way of proof.

Comment: We haven't learnt it at school yet even though I can prove it using that theorem. I suspect since we didn't learn it, it wouldn't be in the answers.

Comment: You are usually allowed to use results you haven't "officially" learned, even though the teacher who gave you the problem had a different solution in mind (unless they specifically forbade you from using a particular technique). Of course, there is no guarantee, and I know there are teachers who are strict about such things.

Comment: Basically you can follow the same steps as the proof of the alternate segment theorem to establish the result.